# Turn a bit array inside a string into week day name

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a varchar which stores data in the format "1111111",where 1 can replace 0 and viceversa.
The length of the string is 7 character, where each character denotes the day of a week.ie. 
for 1010110:the leftmost character(1) denotes monday and right most(0) character denotes sunday and so on and so forth.
I have to write a sql query to get comma separated days from the given string(varchar), whose values are one.
i.e for I/P 0101101 :

O/p should be :Tuesday,Thursday,Friday,Sunday

Comment: What database server? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am using Microsoft Sql Server 2008.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MySQL this is solved this way:

```
select *, 
  concat_ws(',',
    if(substring(days, 1, 1) = '1', 'Monday', null),
    if(substring(days, 2, 1) = '1', 'Tuesday', null),
    if(substring(days, 3, 1) = '1', 'Wednesday', null),
    if(substring(days, 4, 1) = '1', 'Thursday', null),
    if(substring(days, 5, 1) = '1', 'Friday', null),
    if(substring(days, 6, 1) = '1', 'Saturday', null),
    if(substring(days, 7, 1) = '1', 'Sunday', null)
  ) as result
from t1
```

Result of the query:

```
+---------+----------------------------------------------------------+
|  DAYS   |                          RESULT                          |
+---------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| 0101101 | Tuesday,Thursday,Friday,Sunday                           |
| 1010010 | Monday,Wednesday,Saturday                                |
| 1111111 | Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday |
| 0000000 |                                                          |
+---------+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Working [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b042/2)

**Edit:**

MS SQL Server 2008 solution:

```
with ResultTable as (
    select *,
        case when substring(days, 1, 1) = '1' then 'Monday,' else '' end +
        case when substring(days, 2, 1) = '1' then 'Tuesday,' else '' end +
        case when substring(days, 3, 1) = '1' then 'Wednesday,' else '' end +
        case when substring(days, 4, 1) = '1' then 'Thursday,' else '' end +
        case when substring(days, 5, 1) = '1' then 'Friday,' else '' end +
        case when substring(days, 6, 1) = '1' then 'Saturday,' else '' end +
        case when substring(days, 7, 1) = '1' then 'Sunday,' else '' end
        as Result
    from t1
)
select days, substring(result, 0, len(result)) as result
from ResultTable
```

Working [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3b042/69)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am getting this error :"concat_ws is not a recognized built in function name" !!

Comment: Then you're not using MySQL :) Jake asked you, but you didn't answer him.

Comment: Apologies ,I could not see the question. I am using Microsoft Sql Server 2008

Comment: Thanks Gentlemen,
The solution is working perfectly fine.
As I was away from internet , so could not reply early.
Regards,
PM